# What is the easiest way to do this capitalization in python?

Tags: python, capitalization

I have a string:
Name= 'A is an alphabet' 
and I want the output to be 
newName = 'A is An AlphAbet'

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: `newName = Name.replace('a', 'A')`

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong?
Thank you in advance.
code :
name = 'Aradhya anil'
name1 = list(name)
x = len(name1)
lower_case = name1[0].lower()
i = 0
for i in name1:
    if name1[i] == lower_case:
        variable = name1[i].upper()
        name1[i] = variable
        name2 = ''.join(name1)
print(name2)